# Loop and create list in Scala

Tags: scala

I am getting empty list when I am trying to create the list with `::` operator. My code looks like this:

```
def getAllInfo(locks: List[String]): List[LockBundle] = DB.withTransaction { implicit s =>
  val myList = List[LockBundle]()
  locks.foreach(
    l => findForLock(l) :: myList
  )
  myList
} 

def findForLock(lock: String): Option[LockBundle] = { ... }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `flatMap`

```
locks.flatMap(l => findForLock(l))
```

Your code becomes

```
def getAllInfo(locks: List[String]): List[LockBundle] = DB.withTransaction { implicit s =>
  locks.flatMap(l => findForLock(l))
}
```

Alternatively you could use `map` and `flatten`. Something like this `locks.map(l => findForLock(l)).flatten`

Functional programming is all about transformations. You just have to transform your existing list into another list using a transformation which is your function `findForLock`.

**Problem with your code**

```
val myList = List[LockBundle]()
  locks.foreach(
    l => findForLock(l) :: myList
  )
  myList
```

First of all `foreach` returns `Unit` so, you use foreach for side effecting operations and not transformations. As you need transformation so do not use `foreach`.

Next, `findForLock(l) :: myList` gives you a value but this gets ignored as there is no one who is storing the value generated. So, in order to store the value use accumulator and pass it as a function parameter in case of recursion.

**Correcting your code**

If you want to do in your way. You need to use the accumulator.

First fix your types `findForLock(l)` returns `Option`, You list is of type `List[LockBundle]` so change the list type to `List[Option[LockBundle]]`.

In order to get `List[LockBundle]` from `List[Option[LockBundle]]` Just do `flatten` on `List[Option[LockBundle]]` list. See below code snippet

```
  var myList = List[Option[LockBundle]]()
  locks.foreach(
    l => myList = findForLock(l) :: myList
  )
  myList.flatten
```

The above way is not functional and is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work, because `foreach` combinator calls given closure for each element, but all you do here is to return expression `findForLock(l) :: myList` which is discarded.

As pamu suggested, you can use `flatMap` on a function to map each element to values returned by `findForLock` and flatten that list, which turns `Option` into element of the list if it's `Some` or nothing if it's `None`.

Keep in mind that this works only because there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Seq`, in general `flatMap` works only if you return the same type as given monad (that in this case is `List` or `Option`).